# how to make two selection fields depends on each other odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

i have a selection field male or female,if male i want the second 
selection field husband or brother or father,if female i want the second selection field wife or sister or daughter

```
here you are my code :

class Relatives(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom_employee.relatives'
    name = fields.Char(string='Name')
    gender = fields.Selection([('m', 'Male'),('f', 'Female')],default='m')
    relative_relationship = fields.Selection(selection='change_relatives')

    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('gender')

    def change_relatives(self):
        if self.gender == 'm':
          self.relative_relationship.Selection=fields.Selection([('s','Son'),('h', 'Husband'),('f','Father')], default='s',string='Relative Relationship')
        elif self.gender == 'f':
            self.relative_relationship=fields.Selection([('d','Daughter'),('w', 'Wife'),('m', 'Mother')], default='d',string='Relative Relationship')
```

Comment: why not using two selection fields ?

Comment: i am using two selection fields but i want if i select male in the first selection field i want the second selection field options to be father or brother or husband, it is not logical to find daughter option between them

Comment: Sorry man, I meant two seelection fields to replace `relative_relationship` field and you can then hide them depending on the first selection field `gender`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value of selection in onchange even in odoo:

you have two choice instead of using selection field use many2one 
relation and change the domain of that field in onchange even.

Second is to define two selection fields and show only one
in the form based on condition using `attrs`, and you can
create a compute selection field   that contain 
the full list of the two fields to save the selected 
value from one of the two,  so you can show it in the other views.
or perform searching on it.

Answer (score 0):

you should use API depends instead onchange.
 @api.onchange('gender') --> @api.depends('gender')